# Viewing disparate data sources using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, http, csv, hsqldb

Within our company we have various development teams who produce / maintain datasets consumed by other non-developer teams.  Typically these non-developer teams access the data directly from SQL Server, often performing cross joins between databases.  This makes our databases tightly coupled and also makes it difficult to re architect applications whose "private" database schema has been exposed for direct queries.

To solve this we'd like to try and encapsulate the data behind APIs that are easy to access by non-developers; given this we're considering CSV datasets served over HTTP.  One drawback of this approach is being unable to join across datasets using SQL.

My question: Can anyone recommend a technology for being able to treat remote HTTP calls as SQL tables?  For example, I'd like to be able to reference http://myservice.com/students as a logical table, with a call being made to myservice when the table is referenced as part of an SQL query.

(I know HSQLDB has this facility for text files so I can go down this route creating temporary text files if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your asking for technologies like `OData` and `WCF data services`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx

You might be able to treat such a data source as a linked server, but you may have to write the provider yourself unless you can find an OLEDB Odata provider.